# Best way to replace an element of a Collection with multiple elements in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have a Collection of String values.  If one of the values is an '*', I'd like to replace that value with 3 others, let's say "X", "Y", and "Z".

In other words, I'd like [ "A", "B", "*", "C"] to turn into ["A","B","X","Y","Z","C"].  Order does not matter, so it is simply get rid of one and add the others.  These are the ways I can think of for doing it, using that example:

```
Collection<String> additionalValues = Arrays.asList("X","Y","Z"); // or set or whatever
if (attributes.contains("*")) {
    attributes.remove("*");
    attributes.addAll(additionalValues);
}
```

or

```
attributes.stream()
          .flatMap(val -> "*".equals(val) ? additionalValues.stream() : Stream.of(val))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this?  Again, order doesn't matter, and ideally I'd like to remove duplicates (so maybe distinct() on stream, or HashSet?).

Comment: Do you have good reason to believe efficiency is an issue?

Comment: Not really.  Just want to learn best practices.

Comment: that would always add the attributes, even if there wasn't a '*'.  I only want it to add the values if the * exists

Comment: Best practice is to focus on readability and maintainability. If you have reason to believe there's a performance concern, do some [benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1553851).

Comment: @shmosel you have right that readability and maintainability are high priority, but since java9 and jigsaw project we can put java on smaller devices than PC, where performance is a priority not readability

Comment: @ThomasBanderas Well sure, that's true since way before Java 9. But that would be a reason to believe performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that second one is better. `Arrays.asList("X","Y","Z")` retrieve `ArrayList` i.e. an array. It is not good for replace values in it.

In general case, if you want to modify a colletion (e.g. replace `*` with `X`,`Y` and `Z`), the do create **new** collection in some way.

Do look at `LinkedList` if you want to modify collection itself.

*Using Streams:*

```
public static List<String> replace(Collection<String> attributes, String value, Collection<String> additionalValues) {
    return attributes.stream()
                     .map(val -> value.equals(val) ? additionalValues.stream() : Stream.of(val))
                     .flatMap(Function.identity())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Not using Streams*

```
public static List<String> replace(Collection<String> attributes, String value, Collection<String> additionalValues) {
    List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();

    for (String attribute : attributes) {
        if (value.equals(attribute))
            res.addAll(additionalValues);
        else
            res.add(attribute);
    }

    return res;
}
```

*Demo:*

```
List<String> attributes = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "*", "C");
List<String> res = replace(attributes, "*", Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z"));  // ["A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z", "C"]
```

Comment: additionalValues can be any kind of collection, it's just how I happened to define the list up there.  In the actual code, it's a collection coming through the method, so it has already been defined elsewhere

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying for creating a new list now. Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it very similarly to your first way:

```
if (attributes.remove("*")) {
    attributes.addAll(additionalValues);
}
```

You don't need a separate `remove` and `contains` call [for a correctly-implemented collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

> [`Collection.remove(Object)`] Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, **if it is present** (optional operation). More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if this collection contains one or more such elements. **Returns true if this collection contained the specified element** (or equivalently, if this collection changed as a result of the call).

Comment: wow, totally forgot .remove() returned a boolean.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, and to insert replacement values in the correct position, use [`indexOf(o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-), [`remove(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-), and [`addAll(index, c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-):

*Demo*

```
List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "*", "C"));
Collection<String> additionalValues = Arrays.asList("X","Y","Z");

int idx = attributes.indexOf("*");
if (idx != -1) {
    attributes.remove(idx);
    attributes.addAll(idx, additionalValues);
}

System.out.println(attributes);
```

*Output*

```
[A, B, X, Y, Z, C]
```

If order doesn't matter, use the return value of [`remove(o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

```
if (attributes.remove("*"))
    attributes.addAll(additionalValues);
```

*Output*

```
[A, B, C, X, Y, Z]
```